# Outputting multiple lines of text

Tags: r, string, concatenation

I have two numeric lists that I would like to output as text in shiny, but I am having difficulty outputting multiple lines. Say the two lists are:

```
violations1 <- c(1,2,3,5)
violations2 <- c(66,354,78)
```

and for output I would like to see:

```
Violations of Type 1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Violations of Type 2: 66, 354, 78
```

but when I use

```
paste("Violations of Type 1:", violations1, "Violations of Type 2:", violations2)
```

I get

```
[1] "Violations of Type 1: 1 Violations of Type 2: 66" 
[2] "Violations of Type 1: 2 Violations of Type 2: 354"
[3] "Violations of Type 1: 3 Violations of Type 2: 78" 
[4] "Violations of Type 1: 5 Violations of Type 2: 66"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `collapse` option of `paste`:

```
#data
violations1 <- c(1,2,3,5)
violations2 <- c(66,354,78)

#result
paste("Violations of Type 1:",paste(violations1,collapse = ","))
#[1] "Violations of Type 1: 1,2,3,5"
paste("Violations of Type 2:",paste(violations2,collapse = ","))
#[1] "Violations of Type 2: 66,354,78"
```